# How to make a virtual category NOT visible in filters left bar

Tags: category, collection, filter, virtual

I have virtual categories with products in them to be able to display them as a productpage with products from the same series/collection.

I don't want these categories to be visible in my filters in the left bar....
I can't find any possibility to do this.

There is a button-option to 'disable visibility in left bar' but it doesn't work.
Does anybody know how to do this?